# Unexpected "none" when using extend()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Code:

```
l1 = eval(input("Enter the elements"))
l2 = []
l3 = []
l = len(l1)
l2.extend(l1[0:l//2])
l3.extend(l1[l//2:l+1] 
print(l2)
print(l3)
print(l3.extend(l2))
```

Output:

```
Enter the elements[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
None
```

Please tell why the code is showing None as the output

Comment: Is this Python? Please edit your question to add the language as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

the extend method doesn't return a value, here is a simple example:

```
print([1].extend([2]))
```

**output:**

```
None
```

if you want to print the value after you apply the extend method you should first extend your list then print your list:

```
l3.extend(l2)
print(l3)
```